# how do you stop a Fixed position div from overlapping?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

How do I make my fixed position box not underlap the footer?

http://www.designobvio.us/smartklubben/category/resources

```
<div id="cata">
```

I want to add padding or something to stop it short of overlapping.  Anyone have a solution ?  where would I add the padding ?

Thanks so much!

Comment: remove position fixed from cata and things will be normal

Comment: i want the fixed position i just wna tit to stop when it hits the black

Comment: your footer is fixed removing fix from cata will solve this,or I am not understanding this :( sorry

Comment: I want the cata to scroll with the page.  However I want the cata to stop scrolling when it hits black footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement may be you have use `Sticky footer` for this. Check this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: i dont think this is what I need?

Comment: I guess he want the aside thing to scroll and not to touch the footer in any case..am i right mathew?and according to me sticky footer will help you out..

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do both left and right 0  do one or the other.